# How do I loop through a JSON array?

Tags: arrays, json, discord.js

I have a Discord.js bot, I wanted to make a `lockdown` command, but my channel ids are stored in a JSON file, and I dont know how to iterate through it. This is the JSON configuration:

```
{
    "channels": {
        "main": {
            "id": "691548147922763825"
        },
        "creations": {
            "id": "700390086390448148"
        },
        "fanart": {
            "id": "691551615873843211"
        },
        "memes": {
            "id": "691549417173680148"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I loop through it? I know that just doing forEach on a JSON file doesnt work, so I need some help.

Comment: `channels` is not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use for..in loops on objects to get the keys and iterate over them. Objects don't implement the Iterable interface, so `for...of` doesnt work. And `forEach` is not a method on an object, but on an array.

```js
const json = {
    "channels": {
        "main": {
            "id": "691548147922763825"
        },
        "creations": {
            "id": "700390086390448148"
        },
        "fanart": {
            "id": "691551615873843211"
        },
        "memes": {
            "id": "691549417173680148"
        }
    }
}

for( let key in json.channels ) {
  console.log( key, json.channels[key] )
}
```